# SQL/C#: Can i reuse any useful data after concatenating a search query?

Tags: sql, indexing

The query that im using is

```
    SELECT firstName + ', ' + lastName FROM employees
    ORDER BY lastName
```

Which returns a table of values like

Workman, Bob

Nevarez, Ray

and so on, which is what I wanted. I'm using this query to populate a combobox full of employees. My question is, now that these results are put together like that, is it possible to use them in any way as an index? I want to be able to select that person in the combo box, hit the submit button, and have it pull up their profile. But since the combo box is only storing things like "Workman, Bob" im not sure what I would use to find that person in the next query. Does that make sense? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code where you populate the combo box, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferrably, you would use the primary key (probably `employee_id`) from your table as the index.
Your query would look like this (or similar):

```
 SELECT firstName + ', ' + lastName AS fullname, employee_id FROM employees
 ORDER BY lastName
```

Then, you'd use `employee_id` as the value of the option and `fullname` as the text/display. You can then link directly to the user by referencing their ID.

If you went by name only, it's possible two people could have the same name which would no doubt cause you some headaches.

**Edit:**
Using windows forms, you can bind the combo-box to a DataTable (containing your results) by doing something like this:

```
DataTable dt; //populate this however you want with the query above
combobox1.DataSource = dt;
combobox1.DisplayMember = "fullname";
combobox1.ValueMember = "employee_id";
```

Comment: Ok, so the query will be returning 2 values, the fullname column and the empID column. The combobox is only going to populate with the fullname values, what would I do with the empID? I want to be able to select somoneone in that dropdown list and it needs to return the corresponding empID for it to be of any use, right?

Comment: See my latest edit. That will set the value to reference the `employee_id` and the display text to be the `fullname`.

Comment: combobox1.ValueMember = "employee_id"; isn't working. it assigning the literal "employee_id" to everything. any ideas?

Comment: nevermind, im handicapped. I was testing it using combobox.valuemembter instead of combobox.selectedvalue. lol Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT employeeID, firstName + ' ' + lastName AS fullname
FROM employees
ORDER BY lastName
```

Set the `DataValueField` and `DataText` property as follows:

```
DropDown1.DataValueField="employeeID";
DropDown1.DataTextField="fullname";
```